# An Error with DateTime in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, datetime

I am trying to display my dates in format of: `dd/MM/yyyy`.

so I defined `start` and `end` dates:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(NumberOfDaysToDisplayInPreviewPages * (-1));
DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
```

here I want to set the `start` and `end` dates into one string: `dates` that will be in format:

```
`dd/MM/yyyy-dd/MM/yyyy` (for example: 24/12/2013-11/12/2014)
```

so I did:

```
string dates = start.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "-" + end.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

I'm sure it's related to my date format of windows (I don't want to change my dateformat in windows in order to make it works)

[image]

Comment: You don't say what the problem is: do you get an error message? What result does your string actually show? (Note: the code you've posted works just fine for me!)

Comment: No idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use:

```
start.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

the slash will be replaced by a culture-specific date separator.

If you want an explicit / rather than a culture-specific separator, then you have two choices:

- Escape the slash in your format string:

  ```
  start.ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy")
  ```
- Use a culture that has / as its date separator:

  ```
  start.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  ```

Comment: I don't think it's very clear that this is even the problem yet. He says he has an error, not a formatting issue.

Comment: @tnw, true, but the OP also says they're sure it's related to the Windows date format.  So this answer is an educated guess at the problem which might elicit more info from the OP if it's wrong.

Comment: thank you! and if I have this one:

DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(start, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);

what should I do in order to get it in format of: dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss

I tried:

DateTime.ParseExact(start, @"dd\/MM\/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);

but I got:
dd-MM-yyyy

thank you!